# SQL : how to select different rows where values are equal to an set of values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to achieve something like this in SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE servide_id = ('wifi','pulizia','parking','ombrellone','driver','colazione') AND active = 1
```

For example i have an table like:

```
service   |price   |active
wifi       €60      0
park       €20      1
option     €30      1
another    €40      1
```

The query must do something like:

```
1) SELECT * FROM service
2) loop through 'service' column and select WHERE service is = to any value on array
3) check if active is = 1
```

What i want?

```
query:
    SELECT * FROM services WHERE service = ('wifi','park') AND active = 1

result:
    service   |price   |active
    park       €20      1
```

Thanks for your help, I am just starting with SQL :D

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: There is no service_id column, so no.

Comment: Try using `IN` instead of `=`

Comment: Sorry i use SQL on shared hosting...i just clicked wrong tag, sorry

Comment: Where is the array? is it in a table somewhere? If so you could join the tables together.  Otherwise IN instead of = should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SQL [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator to filter on multiple values.

So your query should be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `services` 
WHERE servide IN ('wifi','pulizia','parking','ombrellone','driver','colazione') AND active = 1
```

Comment: You're repeating OP's typo.

Comment: @Kharchi Good to hear! Please consider upvoting and accepting the right answer (there are 3 in here ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Just use `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM `services` 
WHERE service_id IN ('wifi','pulizia','parking','ombrellone','driver','colazione') AND active = 1
```

Comment: Yes, we did! Thanks JChao but i chose to vote for Simon because he posted a bit earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You would use IN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM services
WHERE service IN ('wifi','pulizia','parking','ombrellone','driver','colazione')
   AND active = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks gmiley but i chose to vote for Simon becouse he posted a bit earlier.